# "Write an explicit `.update()` method for serializer" error but update method present

Tags: django-rest-framework

The full error is:

```
The `.update()` method does not support writable nestedfields by default.
Write an explicit `.update()` method for serializer `rest_framework.serializers.BankOutEntrySerializer2`, or set `read_only=True` on nested serializer fields.
```

An update method is present in both the ModelViewSet and ModelSerializer. Both inherit this functionality through a mixin. I'm generating these classes dynamically with `type`.

It looks like this:

```
ViewSet = type(
    Model.__name__+"ViewSet",
    (viewsets.ModelViewSet, DefaultViewSetBehaviour),
    {
        'serializer_class': Serializer,
        'queryset': Model.objects.all()
    }
)
```

The serializer class is also created dynamically in a similar way and recursively generates the appropriate classes including generic update functionality.

What could be causing this? My update methods are never reached.

Answer (score 0):

This was answered in the Django REST framework discussion group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/django-rest-framework/ZT23AsnPzUU

The problem was that the classes/mixins were in the wrong order when inheriting. So instead of (serializers.ModelSerializer, DefaultUpdateBehaviour) it needed to be (DefaultUpdateBehaviour, serializers.ModelSerializer) so as to override the update method in ModelSerializer.